# iMac 21.5" power supply is dead. 220 coming in, nothing coming out

Tags: power-supply

First poster here :)

I have a dead iMac 21.5" here, mid 2010 model. It was running the other day, then all of a sudden it looked like the power was severed and the power in the entire house went off as well (circuit breaker).

From then I've tried other outlets, other cables, but the iMac was dead. I checked the diagnose leds on the logic board and they are all off when the AC cable is connected. Checking diagnostic points on the logic board (tried 1-4) yielded no 12v. (nothing actually).

I then measured the incoming ac points on the power supply and it read 225 volts (I live in Europe, so this is correct :)). However, upon checking all the outgoing rails, none had power.

So I concluded the power supply is faulty. Easy fix (and most expensive one) is replacing it. However, I'm looking for a more DIY solution (replacing fuses/caps). Anyone got any pointers/schematics to do this for this iMac model ?

Thanks for any insights !

idog

Comment: Repair questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

> It was running the other day, then all of a sudden it looked like the power was severed and the power in the entire house went off as well (circuit breaker).

That's a fail-short. The PSU is quite dead and needs to be replaced outright.

> I'm looking for a more DIY solution (replacing fuses/caps). Anyone got any pointers/schematics to do this for this iMac model ?

I doubt it. That kind of damage isn't just a fuse or a cap. It's usually a transistor or diode, which has a habit of taking other things down with it. usually the circuit board itself.

I have yet to see published schematics for any recent Mac. You'd have to reverse engineer it yourself.

As for replacing the supply, see [iFixIt.com](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2389+Power+Supply/6291/1).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the honest answer. I'll order from the iFixit shop or eBay then. I took the supply out using the iFixit website btw, love that site :D